# Typeahead afterselect fill to another input text

Tags: javascript, html, typeahead.js

I want to fill some value to another input text. how to do that?

```
<script>
var projects = new Bloodhound({
    datumTokenizer: function(d) { return Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace(d.idSales); },
    queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
    remote: {
        url: '<?php echo BASE_URL() ?>Sales/getSalesAll?query=%QUERY',
        wildcard: '%QUERY'
    }
});

$('#listSales').typeahead({
        hint: true,
        highlight: true,
        minLength: 0
    },
    {
        name: 'projects',
        display: function(item){ return item.idSales+' – '+item.namaSales},
        source: projects.ttAdapter(),
        templates: {
            empty: [
            ].join('\n'),
            suggestion: Handlebars.compile('<p>{{namaSales}} - {{email}}</strong> </p>')
        }
    });
</script>
```

Here is the html code :

```
<div class="search-form wd-lg-100p">
    <input id="listSales" name="idSales" type="search" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter sales name" required>
    <input id="emailSales" name="emailSales" class="form-control" value="" disabled>
</div>
```

So after im select a value from typeahead `#listSales`, then the email value auto fill the `#emailSales`.
how to do that? thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. I'm using typeahead:select for my cases. Thanks